# `extract()` has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress website it was working for more than 2 months but suddenly a PHP warning `Warning: extract() has been disabled for security reasons in ..` start appearing on the website. What could be reason the reason of this warning? How can i solve this? Is there any alternative for `extract()` function.

Comment: You should contact your host provider, also please be more clear on where and when this error appears. more info = easy to help

Comment: @Vishwa `Warning: extract() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sfwd-lms/includes/class-ld-cpt-instance.php on line 33`..........I think it's happening because of a plugin

Comment: Seems so, it's caused by plugin which should have LMS by dash or similar name. try disabling the plugin and if that plugin is an essential, ask the plugin developer to provide you a fix

Comment: @Vishwa it's cracked lol .... Although i'm trying to fix. What could be the alternative of extract function? Do you have any idea?

Comment: anyway, try asking in their help forum, or look for an alternative. if you want something like course management, moodle will be a better solution(not wp)

Comment: also see here https://elearningindustry.com/top-open-source-learning-management-systems

Comment: @Vishwa i have idea of all these open source management system. Client need system in wordpress.I built it for him. It was working perfectly. But suddenly this warning start appearing and whole website is down.

Comment: then you should look for alternatives or you should ask the developer, then try to buy original plugin. AFAIK, your client could be facing legal problems if it's found that he/she's using cracked version of a plugin

Comment: @Vishwa having the same issue after deactivating all the plugin have any idea what could be the reason.

Comment: do you have cache enabled? could be from the theme itself, cloudflare or any other cdn, cache plugin, or browser cache

Comment: @Vishwa i have found the same error on all websites hosted by the hosting provide i have contacted them they are gonna fix on their site. I have read this [Article](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-extract-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons/). I found the same issue on my side :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my question because i found that it was happening because of my hosting provider. Read this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-extract-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons/) to know more.